# oEmbed for flutter

Tags: twitter, flutter, oembed

This is how we can display a webview url in flutter.

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebviewScaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Browser'),
        ),
        url: "https://twitter.com/gowithkel/status/1137024385229950976");
  }
}
```

But how could a twitter tweet be embeded in flutter?  For example, displaying a twitter tweet that is in oembed format:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Sunsets 
don&#39;t get much better than this one over <a 
href="https://twitter.com/GrandTetonNPS? 
ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">@GrandTetonNPS</a>. <a 
href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/nature? 
src=hash&amp;ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">#nature</a> <a 
href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/sunset? 
src=hash&amp;ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">#sunset</a> <a 
href="http://twitter.com/YuKy2rcjyU">pic.twitter.com/YuKy2rcjyU</a></p>&mdash; 
US Department of the Interior (@Interior) <a 
href="https://twitter.com/Interior/status/463440424141459456? 
ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">May 5, 2014</a></blockquote> <script async 
src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```